$\emptyset \neq X$ compact and Hausdorff; if there is no isolated points, then $X$ is uncountable

$\emptyset \neq X$ compact and Hausdorff; if there is no isolated points, then $X$ is uncountable.

Firstly, I tried to show the following lemma:

Lemma- If $\emptyset \neq U$ is an open set and $x \in X$, then there is a non-empty open set $V \subset U$ such that $x \notin \overline{V}$

Let $\emptyset \neq U$ be an open set and $x \in X$. If $x \in U$, then there is $y \in U-\{x\}$; as $X$ is Hausdorff, there are $N_x,N_y$ open neighbourhoods of $x,y$, respectively, such that $N_x \cap N_y =\emptyset$, so $x \notin \overline{N_y}$ and $N_y \subset U$, because if not so, as $x \in U$, we'd have that $x \in N_y$.
If $x \in \overline{U}-U$, then $V=N_y\cap U$.
Then, I tried to do the following:
Let $x_0,x_1$ be distinct points in $X$ and $N_0,N_1$ disjoint open neighbourhoods of $x_0,x_1$, resp.; then picking two distinct points $x_{00};x_{11}$ from $N_0$ and $N_{00}; N_{01}$ would be two disjoint open neighborhoods; firstly, $V=N_{00}$ and then, using $U=N_0-\overline{N_{00}}$, we'd obtain $V'=N_{01}$. Then,if $i_1 \dots i_k$ is a sequence of $0$'s and $1$'s and
\begin{align*}
\varphi: \{x_{i_1 \dots i_k} \mid k \in \mathbb{N}\} &\rightarrow \mathcal{T}\\
x_{i_1 \dots i_k} &\mapsto N_{i_1 \dots i_k}
\end{align*}
would be a $1$-to-$1$ correspondence and $|X| \geq 2^{\aleph_0}$. What is missing here given that I didn't use every detail obtained from the lemma? Should I prove that the closure of the neighbourhoods are disjoint?

I don't see what would be missing at first glance. Just because you didn't use a lemma doesn't mean this is wrong. The construction seems right to me, you want to construct a copy of the Cantor set in $X$.

the set of finite sequences is countable. You need to show that there is an injection from the set of all functions $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{N}$. Hint: use your construction and the fact that an infinite intersection of nested non empty closed compact sets is non empty.

@GiorgioGenovesi, by way of contradiction , using FIP, we'd obtain that a closed compact of the descending chain would be empty, so we could create a surjective function from $X$ to the infinite sequences of $0$'s and $1$'s and we'd obtain that $|X| \geq 2^{\aleph_0}$?

@JP to be more precise you create an injection from $2^{\aleph_0}$ to $X$, but the idea is that.

The idea of the following proof is essentially the same as the idea of the proof you want to build. The difference is that instead of using multi-index it uses inductively constructed sets and dispenses with the use of Lemma.
The idea of the proof is to show that there exists a set $S$ of sequences $(x_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that $S$ is non-enumerable. Then show that there exists a injective function $\varphi:\mathbb{N}/\{0\}\times S\to X$.
Take a point $x_{0}\in X$. Fix the set $E_{0}=\{x_{0}\}$.  Take any open $U_{0}\ni x_{0}$. Since $X$ has no isolated points, there exists $x_{1}\in U_{0}$ distinct from $x_{0}$. Make $E_{1}=\{x_0,x_1\}$.  By the Hausdorff property there exist open sets
$$
V_{0,1}\ni x_{1} \mbox{ and } U_{0,1}\ni x_{0} \mbox{ such that } V_{0,1}\cap U_{0,1} = \emptyset
$$
In general if $E_{k}$, with $k\geq 2$, has $2^k$ points of $X$ we can obtain a set $E_{k+1}$ with $2^{k+1}$ elements as follows.  Enumerate the elements of $E_k$ with indices from $1$ to $2^k$. Let's say $x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_{i},\ldots, x_{2^k}$. By the Hausdorff property, for the point $x_{i}$ we can obtain $2\cdot(2^k-1)$ open sets
$$
\begin{array}{c}
 V_{i,1}\ni x_{1} \mbox{ and } U_{i,1}\ni x_{i} \mbox{ such that } V_{i,1}\cap U_{i,1} = \emptyset
\\
V_{i,2}\ni x_{2} \mbox{ and } U_{i,2}\ni x_{i} \mbox{ such that } V_{i,2}\cap U_{i,2} = \emptyset
\\
\vdots
\\
V_{i,i-1}\ni x_{i-1} \mbox{ and } U_{i,i-1}\ni x_{i} \mbox{ such that } V_{i,i-1}\cap U_{i,i-1} = \emptyset
\\
V_{i,i+1}\ni x_{i+1} \mbox{ and } U_{i,i+1}\ni x_{i} \mbox{ such that } V_{i,i+1}\cap U_{i,i+1} = \emptyset
\\
\vdots
\\
V_{i,2^k}\ni x_{2^k} \mbox{ and } U_{i,2^k}\ni x_{i} \mbox{ such that } V_{i,2^k}\cap U_{i,2^k} = \emptyset
\end{array}
$$
For all $i\in\{1,2,\ldots, n\}$ fix $U_{i}=\bigcap_{j\neq i}U_{i,j}$. Note that
$$
x_i \in U_{i}, \quad x_j\notin U_{i} \quad \mbox{ and } \quad  U_i \cap U_j=\emptyset \quad  \mbox{ for all } j\in \{1,2,\ldots,2^k\}-\{i\}
$$
Since none of the points $x_i$ is isolated, there is a point $x_{2^k+i}$ \in $U_{i}$ distinct from $x_{i}$ (and distinct from the other $x_\ell \in U_\ell$ since $U_i\cap U_\ell =\emptyset$). So we have a set $E_{k+1}\supset E_{k}$ with $2^{k+1}$ distinct points.
Now let $S$ the set  of all sequences $(x_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that $x_{n}\in E_{n}/E_{n-1}$.  For every  sequence $(x_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ in $S$ we have $x_i\neq x_j$ if $i<j$ because  $x_{j}\in E_{j}/ E_{i}$ and $x_i\in E_{i}$.
Note that for all real number $r=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}d_{k}\cdot 10^{-k}$ in the interval $[0,1]$ whit $d_{k}\in \{0,1,\ldots,8,9\}$ there is a sequence $(x_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ in such a way that for all $u,v\in [0,1]$ whit $u<v$ we can associate distinct sequences in $S$. Therefore $S$ is not enumerable.
Now the final argument. Since $S_i\cap S_j = \emptyset $ for $S_{k}:=E_{k}/E_{k-1}$, $S_{0}=E_0$ and $S=S_0\times S_1\times S_2\times \ldots $ we have the injetive map
$$
\varphi :\mathbb{N}/\{0\}\times S \to X 
$$
defined by
$$
\varphi\Big(m,(x_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\Big)=x_{2^{k-1}+\ell}\in S_{k} 
$$
for $m=2^{k-1}+\ell$  any $x_{2^{k-1}+\ell}\in S_{k}=\{x_{2^{k-1}+1},\ldots, x_{2^{k}}\}$.
